# Arduino LED Lag

Tags: arduino

I'm programming the back lights for a toy car using Arduino. What happens is that if I initiate something like the brake (which turns on all the LEDs), all the LEDs turn on right away but don't turn off right away. When I remove the signal from the LEDs, it takes maybe 5 seconds for the LEDs to actually turn off. Basically there is some kind of a lag or delay. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: It's not really StackOverflow question, besides that there's little someone can do without the circuit diagram.

Comment: Yep. We'd need to see a schematic. Likely a pull-down or pull-up resistor is needed.

Comment: Arduino is not C. Please verify this is actually a software problem, then identify the problem (use a debugger). If you still have a problem, provide a clear description of the problem along with a [mcve] (**note the "Minimal"**).

Comment: Where can I buy LEDs which are still lit after removing current?

Comment: Maybe you should put this question here http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is it ok to use external devices -- for example, 555 timer IC?

Comment: Probably, it's a problem with your serial or something about syncronization that you don't think when coding. Please, post your code or we couldn't do anything

Comment: I was wrong. My comment was about how to make lags.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a serial.write/read then that can cause delays. So perhaps that's one reason. A second reason is, it takes a few moments for the power to drain out of the LED (more likely reason). Is there a some component connected between the ground pin of the LED to the ground rail? Try connecting the negative pin of the LED directly to the ground. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this as soon as I can.